# Angular2: Set change attribute for select in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am dynamically creating dropdowns in my typescript code. That works perfectly fine. However, I cannot figure out how to set the "onchange" event for the dropdowns - so that it triggers whenever the value of the dropdown is changed.

That's my ts code so far:

```
  private createDropDown() {
    const parent = document.getElementById('dropdown-container');
    const sel: any = document.createElement('select');
    sel.setAttribute('id', 'bbCount' + this.bbCount);
    sel.setAttribute('class', 'labelDropdown');
    $('labelDropdown').on('change', e => this.onDropdownChange(e));
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      const opt: any = document.createElement('option');
      opt.setAttribute('text', this.labels[i].value);
      opt.setAttribute('value', String(this.labels[i].id));
      opt.innerText = this.labels[i].value;
      sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
    parent.appendChild(sel);
  }

  public onDropdownChange(e) {
    console.log('event', e);
  }
```

html:

```
  <div style="width: 100%" id="dropdown-container">
  </div>
```

I tried several approaches, the last one was

> $('labelDropdown').on('change', e => this.onDropdownChange(e));

However, this.onDropdownChange(e) is never called or just when the dropdown is created and not when the value is changed.

Does anyone know how I can set the change event on the select inside my typescript code?

Comment: you can emit events during the `(change)` of the dropdown

Comment: but how do I set the (change) attribute for the select?

Comment: in the `HTML` of the dropdown

Comment: It still won't fire. This is jQuery-created HTML node, and Angular won't know how to bind to it.

Comment: but how do I get the change event then? Is there a way?

Comment: can you add the HTML code to the post or create a working example

Comment: there is no html code as I create all the html code inside my typescript code dynamically and then just add it to the "dropdown-container" (which exists in the html already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a lot of things counter to recommended way of doing it with Angular. In this example, you're adding HTML with jQuery, so Angular won't know about these components. And if you hook regular JavaScript events, it's outside of angular's knowledge. You could wrap it in a zone, with some refactoring. Or you could do it the recommended way - create an **angular** dropdown component (can be a simple wrapper around your jQuery), and create an injector that injects this component dynamically.

Another thing is that angular's change would work an an actual select or whatever. So you can make this component implement e.g. custom input control. Then you could hook to it's (change) or (ngModelChange) events in your component.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of how to create it the angular way & then set the "(change)" or "(ngModelChange)" attributes? Because i tried that before as well and it did not seem to work for me

Comment: Totally agree, angular is meant to abstract (most of) the direct DOM manipulation from developers. For dynamic resolution of components take a look here https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d and for a custom component with value accessor here https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83

Comment: I agree with what @Jota.Toledo has said. trexx, the main three things you have to do here are separate. One: create a dynamically injected component. Look up on google, on angular.io, or here on SO, plenty of examples, and then if you get stuck with your specifc code, post another question. Two, try to NOT use jQuery in angular projects. It would be for the best. If you can't avoid it, or not right away, then you can try wrapping jQuery code in a zone and see what happens. That will also be a wide topic and likely extend to many questions :) And three, create custom input.